# Merging multiple JSON files onto one Ruby file

Tags: json, ruby

I am trying to read multiple JSON files and merge them in a ruby file. Here is what I currently have for one that works:

```
require 'json'  
file = File.read(File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)) + '/../attributes.json')  
default.merge! JSON.parse(file)
```

Now if I have the following directory structure where the attributes.json is:

```
attributes.json
Prod
  -JSON1.json
  -JSON2.json
Test
  -JSON1.json
  -JSON2.json
```

How would I accomplish reading all these JSON files on the one ruby file?I am assuming some sort of recursive loop but I can not figure it out.

Comment: No, this will not require recursion in your Ruby code. All you need is [`Dir.glob`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my answer. Here is what I ended up doing:

```
Find.find('/path/to/directory/') do |f|
   next if File.extname(f) != ".json"
   file = File.read(f)
   default.merge! JSON.parse(file)
end
```

I used `Find` which will search for files in any directory and then pass on the file id it does not have a `.json` extension.

Comment: You could use `Dir.glob('/path/to/directory/*.json')` instead of `Find.find` - that would let you get rid of the `next` line.